# More than one params with Rails 5 Action Cable

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

[David has a great video on how to use Action Cable for Rails 5](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n0WUjGkDFS0), for me, I am using the beta 3 version on Rails 5.

The question is, is Action Cable only for a chat app where there is only one parameter passed as `data`? Could I pass more than one params to `speak`?

**RoomChannel (coffee):**

```
App.room = App.cable.subscriptions.create "RoomChannel",
  connected: ->
    # Called when the subscription is ready for use on the server

  disconnected: ->
    # Called when the subscription has been terminated by the server

  received: (data) ->
    alert data['message']
    # Called when there's incoming data on the websocket for this channel

  speak: (message) -> # Could I pass in more than one params?
    @perform 'speak', message: message
```

**room_channel.rb:**

```
# Be sure to restart your server when you modify this file. Action Cable runs in a loop that does not support auto reloading.
class RoomChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    stream_from "room_channel"
  end

  def unsubscribed
    # Any cleanup needed when channel is unsubscribed
  end

  def speak(data)
    ActionCable.server.broadcast 'room_channel', message: data['message']
  end
end
```

If I could pass in more than one params, where would it fit here:

```
App.room.speak("foo bar"); # one param so far here.
```

Edit:

I now got an alert of two objects as: `[object object]`

```
App.room.speak(
    {
      data1: "Data 1 mate",
      data2: "Data 2 mate"
    }
  )
```

**room.coffee:**

```
received: (data1, data2) ->
    alert data1['message']
```

**room_channel.rb:**

```
def speak(data1, data2)
    ActionCable.server.broadcast 'room_channel', message: data1['message'], data2['message']
  end
```

**console:**

```
RoomChannel#speak({"message"=>{"data1"=>"Data 1 mate", "data2"=>"Data 2 mate"}})
```

Comment: `App.room.speak(data:{foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar'})` ?

Comment: @7urkm3n Are you saying: `App.room.speak({data1: 'foo', data2: 'bar'});` ?

Comment: did u try that one i commented ? Try that both and let me know. I have not played with actioncable yet, since i just use sockets with node.

Comment: Nothing. Error in the hash format.

Comment: Is just string working when passing it like "foo bar" ?

Comment: Yes, only as normal. Now when I need more than one data.

Comment: Also try again send an object, but this time remove data['measage'] and make it message: data in the room chanel

Comment: Have you tried this? Im getting too many errors.

Comment: I have not, but all sockets supports object data too. You are smth doing wrong there. Check sending and broadcastings

Comment: Hmmm. See my updated post.

Answer (score 0):

To pass another param to the actioncable server, you can pass a Javascript Object.

Then on the server side, this Javascript object is represented as a hash.

example:

client side

```
App.room.speak(
    {
      param1: "Data 1 mate",
      param2: "Data 2 mate"
    }
  )
```

server side

```
def speak(data)
    ActionCable.server.broadcast 'room_channel', param1: data['param1'], param2: data['data2']
  end
```

and back to the client

```
received: (data) ->
    alert data['param1']
    alert data["param2"]
```

Comment: This looks like it. I'll try this out later. Thanks.

Comment: Tried but both alerts say "undefined".

Answer (score 0):

I guess I can now answer this question. Both params are passed but as an hash. In the console you'll see both params so you'd need to extract the values from `message`.

Keep the `speak` method as normal:

```
def speak(data)
  ActionCable.server.broadcast 'room_channel', message: data['message']
end
```

Your `receive` function (coffee), should look like this:

```
received: (data) ->
  alert(data.message.data1)
  alert(data.message.data2)
```

Comment: I am having the same issue. Can you expand your reply?
At Console (browser) how do you send the message?
`App.room.speak( ???? )`

Answer (score 0):

You must pass a hash on the broadcast call, for example:

```
def broadcast_to_room_channel(title, message)
    data = { title: title, message: message }
    ActionCable.server.broadcast 'room_channel', data
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar situation, where I needed to pass associated `id` params.  I used a `form_with` helper and data attributes, passing the params through speak to create an instance of a `Post`.  I found that something like this worked:

**view.html.erb**

```
<%= form_with(model: Post.new) do |f| %>
    <div>
      <%= f.text_area :content, 
          id: 'text', 
          data: { first_id: @first.id, second_id: @second.id } %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

**chat_room.coffee**

```
speak: (post) ->
firstId = document.getElementById('text').dataset.firstId
secondId = document.getElementById('text').dataset.secondId

@perform 'speak', post: post, first_id: firstId, second_id: secondId
```

**chat_room_channel.rb**

```
def speak(data)
    Post.create! content: data['post'], first_id: data['first_id'], second_id: data['second_id']
end
```

Riffing on the same video that you referenced, i've moved the `broadcast` logic to a worker, where you broadcast your newly created `Post` instance to a partial that you access via `ApplicationController.renderer`.